# matplotlib axis-independent version of set_xlim() and set_ylim()?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a matplotlib axis-independent version of set_xlim() and set_ylim()?

I have a function `setup_axis(ax, ...)` which operates on each axis separately, and I would like to call `ax.set_lim()` the way I can call `ax.set_ticks()` and `ax.set_ticklabels()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `set_data_interval`.  So, for instance, I could say

```
ax = plt.subplot(111)
plt.plot(x, y)
plot.axis((0, 10, -5, 5))
```

or

```
ax.xaxis.set_data_interval(0, 10)
ax.yaxis.set_data_interval(-5, 5)
```

The issue is that this assumes you either know the type of coordinate system used (there may be a way to find this out) or you have the `axis` objects (ie, `ax.xaxis` and `ax.yaxis`) beforehand.

Have a look for more info: http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html